# Moisture meter or water globes?

Tags: watering

I’m considering a moisture meter or watering globes/bulbs to help with watering my plants. My boyfriend will be caring for our plants in Los Angeles while I’m away for work for a month. He doesn’t have much of a green thumb so I want to get something to hopefully help in avoiding under or overwatering. What would be better in this case, a moisture meter or watering globes?

My outdoor plants: two lemongrass, two lavender (in one container), two aloe cuttings (in one container), two succulents (in one container); recently planted California poppy seeds and Iceland poppy seeds, each in their own container.
(Do watering globes even work for seeds?)

My indoor plants: dumb cane (next to south-facing window), zebra succulent (across from south-facing window), and jade pothos (in bathroom, occasionally moved near east-facing window). However, if water globes are the better option, I will only use them on my outdoor plants.

Answer (score 1):

Moisture meter.

Get one long enough to get to the bottom of the pot.

Take top/mid/bottom measures during your prep time before you go to find out what the normal levels are when you water.

Getting some plastic tags, and measure what you normally water.  WRite on the tag, "3 cups"  You can measure easily by starting with your watering can, and water a plant normally, then measure what it takes to refil.  With practice you can change 3 cups into "10 seconds."

Moisture meters are fragile.  Do NOT drop.  Do not leave stuck in pot.  Clean at the end of the job, especially that tiny crack behind the tip.